# While trying to Reindexing through the command prompt generate error

Tags: magento2, reindex, cli

Command I used :

php bin/magento indexer:reindex[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup **php** to your **PATH** environment variable.

> Go to Control Panel > System>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables
>
> Click new
>
> **Variable name : path
>
> Variable value : C:\xampp\php;**

Then restart **cmd**, and try running again the Magento commands.

And it should work.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but the same error is repeated.

Comment: do you have composer lock file in your Magento root folder? along with composer json

Answer (score -1):

I would just remove the php from the  beginning of the command.  Just do bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I followed your instruction not working.